# Is Javascript required to redirect to success page after return statement?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am processing some data in my `views.py` file in django and would like to redirect to a `success.html` page after my `return response`.

I have tried to put several functions (which process dataframes using pandas) inside one function and then call upon the main function but for some reason I get (pandas) errors inside the nested functions when this is done.

```
def download_attachment():
    file_path = 'media/payroll.xlsx'
    response = HttpResponse(open(file_path, 'rb').read())
    response['Content-Type'] = 'mimetype/submimetype'
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=payroll.xlsx'
    return response
```

This is the function for downloading the file. After this function is where I would like to redirect *preferably* without having to implement Javascript.

Comment: It is not possible to download *and* redirect via HTTP alone - there has to be client side support if "redirect after download" is desired. For most sites, I would probably just expect a *asynchronous* download with a displayed page similar to "Your download is starting, if it doesn't boink bloop. You can return to blah blah or click bork blark."

Comment: So I am guessing the best way to do this would be to implement Javascript which watches for a button click and then send an HTTP request to ask the server for the data. Then the server send an HTTP response with the file attachment?